# Grafana Generic OAuth2 implementation

Tags: oauth-2.0, grafana

For a couple of days now, I'm trying to setup generic OAuth2 for grafana. There seems to be little to no examples and documentation that [is provided](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-security/configure-authentication/generic-oauth/) does not explaing the internal things that much. Maybe someone has already done it and will see where I've messed up. Long story short: I have docker setup.

grafana.ini

```
[server]

# The http port  to use
http_port = 3000

# The public facing domain name used to access grafana from a browser
domain = ip0-199

# The full public facing url you use in browser, used for redirects and emails
# If you use reverse proxy and sub path specify full url (with sub path)
root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s:80/grafana

[auth.generic_oauth]
enabled = true
name = SVCluster
allow_sign_up = false
icon = signin
client_id = sentiveillance
email_attribute_path = email
login_attribute_path = userName
id_token_attribute_name = ssAuthData.accessToken
auth_url = http://ip0-199/login
token_url = http://ip0-199/oauth/token
api_url = http://ip0-199/oauth/check_token
use_refresh_token = true
role_attribute_path = contains(authorities[*], 'ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR') && 'Admin'
```

Everything is under nginx reverse proxy. Grafana: `http://ip0-199/grafana`; I have my login page in `http://ip0-199/login`. Authorization endpoint is `http://ip0-199/oauth/authorize`. It get's called from `/login` after pressing log-in button (my `http://ip0-199/oauth/authorize` is just an api endpoint with no UI, so I can't call it directly). I handle the request in `/login` page, set the `Token` in `Session storage`.

Token Example:

```
 Key: ssAuthData
 Value:{"accessToken":"aAXaxBhSwzpQ5keoW9KyybvYLu0","tokenType":"bearer","refreshToken":"iMrI0aSRopOXeMZZKUT1CteTeMQ","validUntil":"2024-03-04T12:00:38.974Z","user":{"id":8,"userName":"admin","email":"admin@admin.admin","authorities":["ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR"]}}
```

Then I redirect back to `http://ip0-199/grafana/login/generic_oauth`, but it just redirects me back to the `/login` page. If I go back to the `http://ip0-199/grafana/login` page, I can see, that `Token` in `Session storage` is set and available. What did I miss here? Or am I wrong how Grafana handles these situations/setups?

Comment: Use standard debugging: increase Grafana log level to debug and watch Grafana server logs first. You can have millions problem there: e.g. serving from subpath, I'm not sure if your auth server is OAuth compatible, .....